# How to Add implementation to Interface code contract when inheriting off interface

Tags: c#, interface, code-contracts

My example is a situation where the interfaces that inherit of the base interface need to add post conditions that are a result of their additional fields - the example occured when i decided to have an IInitialise interface as interfaces that inherit from this invariably want a pre/post condition added to the Initialise method.

I can see that the problem is due to the abstract implementations having no way to avoid each other (either due to interception or the rewriter).

```
    [ContractClass(typeof(IInitialiseContract))]
    public   interface IInitialise
    {
        bool IsInitialised { get; }
        void Initialise();

    }

    [ContractClassFor(typeof(IInitialise))]
    public abstract class IInitialiseContract : IInitialise
    {

        public bool IsInitialised
        {
            get { return default(bool); }
        }

        public void Initialise()
        {
            Contract.Ensures(IsInitialised == true);
        }
    }
```

then later I end up with the following interface

```
  [ContractClass(typeof(IEnginecontract))]
    public interface IEngine : IInitialise 
    {
        ICommandManager CommandManager { get; }
        IDictionary<int, IEntity> World { get; } 
    }

    [ContractClassFor(typeof(IEngine))]
    public abstract class IEnginecontract : IEngine
    {

        public ICommandManager CommandManager
        {
            get
            {
                Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ICommandManager>() != null);
                return default(ICommandManager);
            }
        }

        public IDictionary<int, IEntity> World
        {
            get
            {
                Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IDictionary<int, IEntity>>() != null);
                return default(IDictionary<int, IEntity>);
            }
        }

        public bool IsInitialised
        {
            get { return default(bool); }
        }

        public void Initialise()
        {
            // I would like to put my pre and post conditions here but 
            // cannot because it is implemented in the base interfaces contract.
        }
    }
```

I get to here and i cannot figure out a nice clean way to add conditions to Initialise().

Edit2: If I had put a requires in this method i would of got an error like this

Warning 1   Contract class IEngine cannot define contract for method IInitialise.Initialise as its original definition is not in type IEngine . Define the contract on type IInitialise instead.    IEngine .cs

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the exact problem? s there an error? A Warning somewhere?

Comment: oh with this code no warning ... I would want to add a requires or ensures into the Initialise method in the contract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. I use code contracts extensively and as far as I can tell -- I remember having tried something like this myself -- your derived interface's code contract must include all conditions again, it cannot inherit them.

Comment: sadly i suspect you are correct ... if noone gives me a better answer in the next month i will mark correct ;)

Answer (score 3):

Any methods which are from an interface other than the one you're writing the contracts for should be marked `abstract`. The contracts for these methods will be inherited automatically, and you can't change them (or this would alter the meaning of the base interface, which doesn't make sense).

So you should have your base interface and its contracts:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IInitialiseContract))]
public interface IInitialise
{
    bool IsInitialised { get; }
    void Initialise();

}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IInitialise))]
public abstract class IInitialiseContract : IInitialise
{

    public bool IsInitialised
    {
        get { return default(bool); }
    }

    public void Initialise()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(IsInitialised == true);
    }
}
```

And your derived interface and its contracts (note abstract inherited ones):

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IEnginecontract))]
public interface IEngine : IInitialise 
{
    ICommandManager CommandManager { get; }
    IDictionary<int, IEntity> World { get; } 
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IEngine))]
public abstract class IEnginecontract : IEngine
{

    public ICommandManager CommandManager
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ICommandManager>() != null);
            return default(ICommandManager);
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<int, IEntity> World
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IDictionary<int, IEntity>>() != null);
            return default(IDictionary<int, IEntity>);
        }
    }

    public abstract bool IsInitialised {get;}
    public abstract void Initialise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that added info. I didn't think of trying that it avoid implementing the methods - I don't think this approach was in the documentation when i learnt them!

Comment: I disagree with altering the meaning of the base interface. This is a modification that will rely on the new inhetired inheritance and so is an additional requirement on a more specialised interface definition. There is no altering of the origional interface implied. I know the justification in the documentation, but this is not a situation where i want to achieve the equivalent of the new keyword in a method definition ... for instance what if i want to explicitly implement the interface?

Comment: I agree that there are cases where it should be possible. Perhaps I should have worded the line in a different way - it's the *implementation* which is restricting your options here.

Comment: yeah i agree. the thing is what you said is the view of the authors of code contracts (or at least that of the person who wrote that part of the documentation - I remember reading it and thinking 'yeah that makes sense', now I think its not a great reason ;)